# Prove whether $\frac{a_0}{a - a_1} < - \frac{b}{( 1 - \frac{c}{\theta} ) a}$ always holds

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

I am having a hard time proving which term is bigger:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_0}{a - a_1} \quad \text{vs} \quad - \frac{b}{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{\theta} \right) a} 
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
c = \lambda (\epsilon - 1)(1+\varphi) > 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a &= \frac{- \delta \theta + \sqrt{\delta^2 \theta^2 + 4 c ( \epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi) }}{2 c} \nonumber \tag{2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \frac{- \delta \theta + \sqrt{\delta^2 \theta^2 + 4 \theta (\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)}}{2 \theta}  \tag{3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a_0 &= - \frac{b a_1}{\delta + a_1} \nonumber \tag{4}
\end{align}
The following restrictions must be respected:
\begin{align}
0 &< c < \theta \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
b > 0 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a_0 < 0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
0 < a_1 < a
\end{align}
and $\epsilon > 1$, $\varphi > 0$, $\delta > 0$, $\theta > 0$, $\lambda > 0$.

Does anyone have a good idea to approach this? I am interested in understanding whether one term is always bigger than the other, rather than whether one term can be bigger than the other under some specific parameters.

**My attempt:**

I have reduced the problem to the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_0}{a - a_1} &< - \frac{b}{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{\theta} \right) a} \\
- \frac{b a_1}{(\delta + a_1)(a - a_1)} &< - \frac{b}{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{\theta} \right) a} \nonumber \\
\frac{a_1 a}{(\delta + a_1)(a - a_1)} &> \frac{\theta}{\theta - c } \nonumber \\
\end{align}
I have been trying to solve this inequality but with little success.

Comment: IMHO, your issue has too many parameters ; you should simplify it. Besides, there are many questions 1) what are $x$ and $A,Ax$ in $\sigma^x, \sigma^{A},\rho_t^{Ax}$ ; hopefuly not exponents, but why do you keep such complicated notations ? 2) $a$ and $a_1$ are visibly roots of quadratics 3) No sign information on $\delta, \epsilon, etc$ which aren't present in the three final inequalities...

Comment: I apologize. I have simplified the notation and added more info on the signs of the coefficients. You were absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

Let us prove that
$$\frac{a_0}{a - a_1} < - \frac{b}{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{\theta} \right) a}.$$

From (3), we have
$$\varphi = \frac{a_1 \theta (a_1 + \delta)}{\epsilon - 1} - 1. \tag{5}$$

Using (1), (2) and (5), we have
$$\lambda = \frac{a_1^2 + a_1\delta - a\delta}{(a_1 + \delta)a^2 a_1^2}. \tag{6}$$

Using (1) and (6), we have
$$c = \frac{(a_1 \delta + a_1^2 - a\delta)\theta }{a^2}. \tag{7}$$

From (4), we have
$$b = - \frac{a_0 (a_1 + \delta)}{a_1}.\tag{8}$$

Using (7) and (8), we have
$$\frac{a_0}{a - a_1} - \left(- \frac{b}{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{\theta} \right) a}\right)
= - \frac{ca^2}{\theta}\cdot \frac{-a_0}{a_1(a - a_1)(a + a_1 + \delta)} < 0. \tag{9}$$

We are done.